# Gatsby/GraphQL throws error when using emojis in Contentful content type name

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-plugin

I'm building my first Contentful project. In the Contentful demo setups they are using emojis in the content type names. I have also got this recommendation from a contentful representative. And it seems like a good idea to keep your content types organized:

[image: Content type names]

The app should be run on GatsbyJS. So I initiated a

```
npx gatsby new gatsby-starter-contentful-homepage https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-contentful-homepage
```

I have also setup the gatsby-config.js for `gatsby-source-contentful` like so:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_CDA_TOKEN,
      },
}
```

But when I run `gatsby develop` I get this GraphQL error. It seems like emojis can't be used in Contentful content type names together with Gatsby.

```
info Contentful: 0 deleted assets
info Creating 1 Contentful Link nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Contact me form (not in beta) nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Framework nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Office nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Editorial card (not in beta) nodes
info Creating 7 Contentful  Common page nodes
info Creating 4 Contentful ✨ Product structure item nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Category list nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Product list nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Article page nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Ecom common nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Cart nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Checkout - Unloading nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Checkout nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Checkout - Delivery time nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Checkout - Delivery address nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful ✨ Checkout - Delivery recipient nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Favorites nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Rich text nodes
info Creating 1 Contentful  Order confirmed nodes
info Creating 6 Contentful asset nodes
success Contentful: Create nodes - 0.205s
success Contentful: Process data - 0.237s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.002s
success source and transform nodes - 1.098s

 ERROR 

Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but
"Contentful✨ContactMeFormNotInBeta" does not.'. Stacktrace was 'GraphQLError: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but
"Contentful✨ContactMeFormNotInBeta" does not.
    at isValidNameError (C:\customername\node_modules\graphql\utilities\assertValidName.js:42:12)
    at assertValidName (C:\customername\node_modules\graphql\utilities\assertValidName.js:21:15)
    at checkIsAllowedTypeName (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:619:3)
    at forEach (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:297:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at addTypes (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:258:9)
    at updateSchemaComposer (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:130:9)
    at buildSchema (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\schema.js:71:9)
    at build (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\schema\index.js:112:18)
    at buildSchema (C:\customername\node_modules\gatsby\src\services\build-schema.ts:19:3)'
```

Has anyone had this issue before?

Should I remove the emojis or am I missing something?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the contentful integration for Gatsby. The generated names do not conform with the GraphQL specification that states that names must be relatively plain. Maybe the plugin could just drop these letters? I think it would be best to open an issue/bug report on the repository of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite self-explanatory:

> Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was
> 'Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but
> "Contentful✨ContactMeFormNotInBeta" does not.'. Stacktrace was
> 'GraphQLError: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but
> "Contentful✨ContactMeFormNotInBeta" does not.

My guess is that the error will be gone when you remove the emoji since they are Unicode types that won't validate the following regular expression: `/^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`

Comment: I get that. But since Contentful promotes the use of emojis in the content type names, and since this is my first project with contentful + gatsby, I was wondering if Im doing something wrong. Because other characters like space and () are sanitized in the gatsby plugin. But not emojis. Isn't that a bug since it's supported in Contentful but not in the gatsby-source-contentful plugin?

Comment: Indeed. Contentful has dozens of integrations where the emoji Unicode characters can be valid. It seems to break the regular expression in `gatsby-source-contentful` plugin